# JAVA - Form Loaded With Errors - How can I import and open a project that uses JCalendar.1.4? (NetBeans)

Tags: java, forms, import, netbeans, jcalendar

[image: image of the problem]

I get the following error message when I try to use a form in this project. The project uses the library  JCalendar.1.4. I already downloaded the library and I did this to add it
I clicked on:

- Tools
- Palette - Swing/AWT Components
- I created a New Category called "JCalendar"
- Add from JAR. Then I selected the folder where I have the library and I chose all the components to add them to my palette.
  I did not work. I'm a very beginner so this is the first time I try to do this.

Comment: Have you tried to compile your project before opening the form in the GUI editor?